# Why does Synapse spark.read return garbled MongoDB _id values?

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Using a CosmosDBMongoDB linked service, from Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB, to a Synapse Analytics workspace.

EDIT: I can confirm that the `objectID` values in the Cosmos/ Mongo DB are valid, since they are used in an application.

Document snippet, as seen in CosmosDB Data Explorer

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("623a3902764504df1bc51620"),
    "name": "Dummy data"
}
```

The Analytical Storage Time to Live option is On in the CosmosDB collections, meaning they show up in the Linked section in Analytics studio.

In a Synapse notebook running

```
spark.sql("select unhex('623a3902764504df1bc51620') as bytes").show(truncate=False)
```

returns

```
+-------------------------------------+
|bytes                                |
+-------------------------------------+
|[62 3A 39 02 76 45 04 DF 1B C5 16 20]|
+-------------------------------------+
```

indicating a working PySpark environment. However

```
df = spark.read\
    .format("cosmos.olap")\
    .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "CosmosDbMongoDb1")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.container", "TABLENAME")\
    .load()

display(df.limit(10))
```

returns

```
"{"objectId":"b:9\u0002vE\u0004�\u001b�\u0016 "}"
objectId: ""b:9\u0002vE\u0004�\u001b�\u0016 ""
```

for all values in `_id` column.

EDIT: `df.printSchema()` returns

```
root
 |-- _rid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _ts: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _etag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- objectId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
..... snip ...
```

Running `df3 = df.select(unhex("_id.objectId"))` returns

```
+-------------------+
|unhex(_id.objectId)|
+-------------------+
|               null|
|               null|
+-------------------+
```

Running `df.select(unhex('_id.objectId'))` returns

```
DataFrame[unhex(_id.objectId): binary]
```

Running

```
SELECT TOP (100) JSON_VALUE([_id], '$.objectId') AS _id
 FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLENAME]
```

in the built-in SQL pool returns the same garbled `b:9vE��` values.

Trying

```
%%sql
    create table TABLENAME using cosmos.olap options (
        spark.synapse.linkedService 'CosmosDbMongoDb1',
        spark.cosmos.container 'TABLENAME'
)

SELECT name, _id
FROM TABLENAME;
```

returns for the `_id` column

```
"{"schema":[{"name":"objectId","dataType":{},"nulla..."
schema: "[{"name":"objectId","dataType":{},"nullable":true,..."
0: "{"name":"objectId","dataType":{},"nullable":true,"..."
name: ""objectId""
dataType: "{}"
nullable: "true"
metadata: "{"map":{}}"
map: "{}"
values: "["b:9\u0002vE\u0004�\u001b�\u0016 "]"
0: ""b:9\u0002vE\u0004�\u001
```

Sorry for the copypaste additional garble there are expandable fields in the column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Scala code example in [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction#working-with-the-mongodb-_id-field) that works for converting `ObjectId` field to string:

```
val df = spark.read.format("cosmos.olap")
.option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "xxxx")
.option("spark.cosmos.container", "xxxx")
.load()

val convertObjectId = udf((bytes: Array[Byte]) => {
    val builder = new StringBuilder

    for (b <- bytes) {
        builder.append(String.format("%02x", Byte.box(b)))
    }
    builder.toString
}
)

val dfConverted = df.withColumn("objectId", col("_id.objectId")).withColumn("convertedObjectId", convertObjectId(col("_id.objectId"))).select("id", "objectId", "convertedObjectId")

display(dfConverted)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Synapse/blob/main/Notebooks/PySpark/Synapse%20Link%20for%20Cosmos%20DB%20samples/E-Commerce/spark-notebooks/pyspark/01-CosmosDBSynapseMongoDB.ipynb),

> Cosmos DB automatically transforms the BSON data (Binary JSON) into a columnar format.

However, you are still getting an error because of the **ObjectId** type.

In Spark, there is no **ObjectId** type, so it doesn't recognize the type and gives an error like this. [These](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html) are the supported data types in Spark.

To avoid this, you need to create or ingest data with an `_id` provided, because if you don't provide the `_id`, it will be automatically added like below: `ObjectId("623a3902764504df1bc51620")`.

Below are two records created: one with an autogenerated `_id` and another with a manually created `_id`.

**Autogenerated**

[image]

**Manually added**

[image]

Output:
[image]

Below is the code used to add data to Cosmos MongoDB for the container **HTAP2**.

```py
from random import randint
import time
import uuid

client = MongoClient(connection_string)
db = client.samp # get database

orders = db["HTAP2"] #get container

items = ['Pizza','Sandwich','Soup', 'Salad', 'Tacos']
prices = [2.99, 3.49, 5.49, 12.99, 54.49]

for x in range(1, 501):
    random_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    
    order = {
        '_id' : str(random_uuid),
        'item' : items[randint(0, (len(items)-1))],
        'price' : prices[randint(0, (len(prices)-1))],
        'rating' : randint(1, 5),
        'timestamp' : time.time()
    }
    
    result=orders.insert_one(order)

print('finished creating 500 orders')
```

Output:

[image]

So, make sure to add an `_id` when adding data to Cosmos DB.

Refer this [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Synapse/blob/main/Notebooks/PySpark/Synapse%20Link%20for%20Cosmos%20DB%20samples/E-Commerce/spark-notebooks/pyspark/01-CosmosDBSynapseMongoDB.ipynb) for more information.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for effort and the link to the notebook example. My schema is mostly similar to his, with auto created MongoDb `_id` field. The author imports BSON type with `from bson import ObjectId` "to make objectId" work. I have tried the same, but no luck.

Comment: Regarding adding a string type `id` to an existing MongoDB, I'm not sure about the realism in that, since the collections heavily reference each other.

Comment: If wish you can use mongo client from pymongo  which returns correct value.

Comment: Whatever `ObjectId` function returns doesn't support in spark. Try to update the documents from mongo client and fetch using spark. In th aove code I given to `insert_one` instead use update for `_id`  field.

Comment: not sure I agree that `ObjectId` is not supported by the Spark Connector. It seems like more of an issue using `.format("cosmos.olap")`. 
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/batch-mode/batch-read/#schema-inference