# How to use Mongo DB addFields aggregation pipeline in Spark.read?

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to use the [Mongo DB aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/batch-mode/batch-read-config/) in a Synapse Spark notebook. The use case is to convert `ObjectID` type fields, like the `_id` field, to string with [$addFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/).

However, my attempts are met with

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized configuration specified: (pipeline,[{ $addFields: { _id: { '$toString': '$_id' } } } ])
```

I have been trying to brute force quote mark combinations, looking at examples from Copilot and documentation. Here is one example:

```
pipeline = "[{ '$addFields': { '_id': { '$toString': $_id } } } ]"

df = spark.read\
    .format("cosmos.olap")\
    .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "CosmosDbMongoDb1")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.container", "<COLLECTION NAME>")\
    .option("pipeline", pipeline)\
    .load()

display(df.limit(10))
```

Did I make some noob mistake in literal format, or is this a case of missing support in the Spark connector?

EDIT: This paragraph in the [connector docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/batch-mode/batch-read-config/) could very well point to an answer for someone more experienced with MongoDB.

> Custom aggregation pipelines must be compatible with the partitioner > strategy. For example, aggregation stages such as $group do not work > with any partitioner that creates more than one partition.

Answer (score 0):

To convert `ObjectID` type fields, like the `_id` field, to a string, follow the approach below:

1. Define the **Schema** for the data that will be read from Cosmos OLAP.
2. Use the binary type in the schema for the `ObjectID` field.

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("_rid", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_ts", LongType(), True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_etag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_id", StructType([
        StructField("objectId", BinaryType(), True)  # Use BinaryType for objectId
    ]), True),
    StructField("name", StructType([
        StructField("string", StringType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("age", StructType([
        StructField("int32", IntegerType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("marks", StructType([
        StructField("array", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("int32", IntegerType(), True)
        ])), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("newAge", StructType([
        StructField("string", StringType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("_partitionKey", StructType([
        StructField("string", StringType(), True)
    ]), True)
])
```

2. `convert_object_id()` takes a byte array as input and converts it into a hexadecimal string.

```py
def convert_object_id(bytes_array):
    builder = []
    for b in bytes_array:
        builder.append(format(b, '02x'))
    return ''.join(builder)
```

3. The line below registers the UDF with Spark, which is used in Spark DataFrames.

```
convert_object_id_udf = udf(convert_object_id)
```

4. The data is read from Cosmos OLAP using the schema, and the data is read into a DataFrame.

```py
df = spark.read\
    .format("cosmos.olap")\
    .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "CosmosDbMongoDb1")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.container", "secondColl")\
    .schema(schema)\
    .load()
```

5. `dfConverted` creates a new DataFrame by adding `objectId` and `convertedObjectId`.

```py
dfConverted = (
     df.withColumn("objectId", col("_id.objectId"))
    .withColumn("convertedObjectId", convert_object_id_udf(col("_id.objectId")))
    .select("id", "objectId", "convertedObjectId")
)
```

**Code I tried with:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType, IntegerType, ArrayType, BinaryType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("_rid", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_ts", LongType(), True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_etag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_id", StructType([
        StructField("objectId", BinaryType(), True)  # Use BinaryType for objectId
    ]), True),
    StructField("name", StructType([
        StructField("string", StringType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("age", StructType([
        StructField("int32", IntegerType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("marks", StructType([
        StructField("array", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("int32", IntegerType(), True)
        ])), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("newAge", StructType([
        StructField("string", StringType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("_partitionKey", StructType([
        StructField("string", StringType(), True)
    ]), True)
])

def convert_object_id(bytes_array):
    builder = []
    for b in bytes_array:
        builder.append(format(b, '02x'))
    return ''.join(builder)
 
convert_object_id_udf = udf(convert_object_id)
 
df = spark.read\
    .format("cosmos.olap")\
    .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "CosmosDbMongoDb1")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.container", "secondColl")\
    .schema(schema)\
    .load()

dfConverted = (
     df.withColumn("objectId", col("_id.objectId"))
    .withColumn("convertedObjectId", convert_object_id_udf(col("_id.objectId")))
    .select("id", "objectId", "convertedObjectId")
)
 
display(dfConverted)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, this seems like the Python UDF I was looking for. Is it necessary to define the schema before `spark.read`?

Comment: Yes, schema is necessary for `objectId` field because objectId should be of Binary Type.

Comment: I'm not sure which solution to accept, my own answer using Scala code is simpler. Besides that, none of our answers really answers the question about the `$addFields` aggregation stage in Spark connector

Comment: The connector used for `aggregation.pipeline` is `mongodb`, see this for more information about `aggregation.pipeline` [options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/batch-mode/batch-read/) but here you are using `cosmos.olap` for that the pipeline configuration may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I found Scala code example in [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction#working-with-the-mongodb-_id-field) that works for converting `ObjectId` field to string:

```
val df = spark.read.format("cosmos.olap")
.option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "xxxx")
.option("spark.cosmos.container", "xxxx")
.load()

val convertObjectId = udf((bytes: Array[Byte]) => {
    val builder = new StringBuilder

    for (b <- bytes) {
        builder.append(String.format("%02x", Byte.box(b)))
    }
    builder.toString
}
)

val dfConverted = df.withColumn("objectId", col("_id.objectId")).withColumn("convertedObjectId", convertObjectId(col("_id.objectId"))).select("id", "objectId", "convertedObjectId")

display(dfConverted)
```

This solution also answers the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77639406/19240426)